# Error al recorrer datos de un txt en java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al momento de recorrer un archivo `.txt` yo lo puedo leer perfectamente pero hay una parte de ese archivo que quiero omitir y empezar a leer desde otro punto así empieza el archivo

> ```
> Relatório por Data
>
> 31/08/16 MEZCLA III       13:36:57 13:43:22 0                      6,24T
> ```

así tal cual esta pegado el archivo quiero omitir la parte de relatorio por data y empezar a leer desde la fecha este es mi método en java

```
   public void init() {
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    Date myDate = new Date();

    String resultado = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyy").format(myDate);
    try {
        // Apertura del fichero y creacion de BufferedReader para poder
        // hacer una lectura comoda (disponer del metodo readLine()).
        archivo = new File("C:\\texto\\" + resultado + ".txt");
        fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        // Lectura del fichero
        String linea;

        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            columns = linea.split(" ");
            String fechaC = String.valueOf(columns[0]);
            System.out.println(fechaC);

         }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // En el finally cerramos el fichero, para asegurarnos
        // que se cierra tanto si todo va bien como si salta 
        // una excepcion.
        try {
            if (null != fr) {
                fr.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Al momento de hacerle `split` solo me tomo el indice 0 si le coloco 1 me arroja una excepción de `Arrayindex`

Comment: En otras palabras, estás leyendo línea por línea y quieres que no haga nada con lo que lees en las dos primeras líneas (porque no tiene el formato adecuado)... ¿no bastaría con leer las dos primeras líneas antes del bucle?

Comment: si pero quiero omitir solo esa parte en probado varias cosas y no lo consigo hacer

Comment: Haz dos lecturas de línea y no hagas nada con los datos, y luego lee la línea buena y esa es la que procesas.

Comment: como asi podrias explicarmelo con codigo porfavor te lo agradeceria mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error en la lógica del programa, la excepción es porque la segunda línea del archivo es una línea en blanco, dentro de tu bucle while tratas de leer el primer valor que tienes en el arreglo, la segunda línea solo tiene un valor y es por eso que cuando quieres leer el segundo tu programa manda una excepcion.
Si puedes asegurar que tu archivo de texto siempre tiene el mismo formato puedes hacer lo que SJuan76 te sugirió y leer las dos primeras líneas antes del while.

```
br.readLine();
br.readLine();

while()
{
    //Procesar texto
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo con eso ya puse hacer los 2 saltos de linea